# Unable to create iceberg table using Trino

Tags: trino, apache-iceberg

I am trying to create iceberg table using trino but ddl is not executing stating that sort_order not find .below sample ddl

```
Create table <tableschema>.test ( C1 datetime,
C2 double ,
C3 double 
) 
With ( format='parquet',
       Location='S3a:// location of file',
        Partitioning=ARRAY['day(C1)'],
        Sort_order=ARRAY['C2','C3']
)
```

DDL not executing when I am defining the sort_order for table . Without sort_order table getting created. I am using trino-jdbc380.jar for driver to connect

Comment: I dont think trino iceberg connector supports sort clause. I cant find it in docs https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/iceberg.html

Comment: Yes Trino iceberg connectors doesn't support sort order clause . In order to change table properties i used spark

Comment: Could you please share how you changed sort order haing tblproperties ?

Comment: spark.sql("ALTER TABLE <catlog_name>.<schema>.<table_name> WRITE ORDERED BY C2,C3")